# C# Data Binding via code behind doesn't work for Text property in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a textbox with xaml markup like this: 
`<TextBox x:Name="txtHN" Text="{Binding Path=AN}"/>`

The above code works perfectly well. But when i change the data binding implementation from XAML to code-behind, It does not work anymore. The following code-behind does not work anymore:

```
Binding textHnBinding = new Binding();
textHnBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("AN");
txtHN.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textHnBinding);
```

I had set the `textbox.datacontext` to the same collectionviewsource but the code-behind version does not work anymore. I had really no idea what seems to be the culprit.

I use the following code for the CVS.source:

```
                IEnumerable<decimal> ANListWard4 = (from s in context.IPDAN
                                                    where ward.Contains(s.CURRENTWARD)
                                                    select s.AN).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n);
                List<IPDAN> Ward4AN = new List<IPDAN>();
                foreach (decimal d in ANListWard4)
                {
                    IPDAN ward4AN1 = new IPDAN();
                    ward4AN1.AN = d;
                    Ward4AN.Add(ward4AN1);
                }
```

I set the CVS.Source to Ward4AN. There was no instance where the Ward4AN was null, or has no data.

Comment: collectionviewsource to a textbox's text? can you share the sample data of collectionviewsource

Comment: Where do you have that code to set binding (in which event)? You have to share more details about `textbox.DataContext`, it can be the problem. Do you have binding errors in Output window?

Comment: It may seem weird but I set use the textbox as a parameter source for another Linq query link to a second CVS. I do not want to use  a ListBox coz it takes up so much space than a textbox.

Comment: I had check the output window. It has a line like this: System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=AN; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name='txtHN'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
Binding textHnBinding = new Binding("AN");
txtHN.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textHnBinding);
```

This is how I done all my binding so I think it should work.

EDIT :

Long time no uses binding so my apologies if I'm wrong again :

```
Binding textHnBinding = new Binding("AN");
FrameworkElementFactory textHN = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
txtHN.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textHnBinding);
```

Can you try instantiate your Control like this instead of in Xaml to check if it will work (as me) ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if you instantiate it in c#, or you change the name. Dont forgot to add the new textbox (created by code) to your frame.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the collectionViewSource is not null when you are doing the binding.If the object is null when you are adding the binding, the binding might not work.

Also check whether in loaded event it works or not.